# i want to export a function in a javascript file so i can use it in another file but i am getting the error "export 'startConsume' is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, threejs-editor

i was trying to export function from this file to another file but then i am not able to do that .here is the code I want to export the function from but then whe i try to use an export at the end of the file I get the error "export 'startConsume' is not defined"
if anyone could help me i would be much aprreciated.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useFrame, useThree } from "react-three-fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";

const Actor = () => {
  const meshRef = useRef();
  const { scene } = useThree();

  useEffect(() => {
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00000 });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.rotateY(Math.PI);

    // Set initial properties and functions
    mesh.instructions = [];
    mesh.target = new THREE.Object3D().copy(mesh, false);
    mesh.targetRadiansOnY = 0;
    mesh.currentRadiansOnY = 0;
    mesh.mass = 0.1;
    mesh.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
    mesh.angularVelocity = 0.015;
    mesh.topSpeed = 0.05;
    mesh.topAccelleration = 0.0015;
    mesh.accelleration = new THREE.Vector3();
    mesh.currentInstruction = null;
    mesh.gravityForce = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, -0.01, 0.0);

    // Add mesh to the scene
    scene.add(mesh);
    meshRef.current = mesh;

    return () => {
      // Clean up the mesh when the component unmounts
      scene.remove(mesh);
    };
  }, [scene]);



     // Update function to consume commands
    const consumeCommands = (mmm) => {
    console.log('aa')
    };


    const startConsume = (instructions) => {
      console.log(instructions);
  
      // this.instructions = instructions;
      // if(this.instructions.length>0){
      //     this.currentInstruction = this.instructions.shift();
      //     this._consumeCommandsNew(this.currentInstruction);
      // }else{
      //     console.log("no instructions to execute");
      // }
  
    }


    // Set the consumeCommands function as an update function
    useFrame(() => {
      consumeCommands();
    });

  return null; // We don't render anything for this component
};


export {Actor, startConsume};
// export {startConsume};
```

Comment: The startConsume function is private (it belongs to the Actor function and thus cannot be accessed outside the function body). You should not be exporting (or at least trying to) functions or variables that belong to a private scope (such as a function). If you want to execute the startConsume function from some place else, you will need to pass some props to the Actor function or use some kind of parent state that can trigger the execution of the function or some other code within the Actor Component function. Yet another option, would be to create and use a custom Hook.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis thank you for your explanation. But could you do a little demonstration of how I can do that? I am new to javascript so I don't fully have some things on my hand

Comment: it's not easy to give an example as it's unclear from your code how the Actor component will be updated and how/when the startConsume will be executed. You can start by studying the fundamentals: 1) Sharing state across Componentshttps://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components, 2) Props: https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component and 3) Custom Hooks: https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks. At this point it's difficult to say which strategy will be fit for your case unless more context is provided. In any case, try something and come back to SO.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis thank you very much  i have been able to solve it